# Create nameserver for a specific domain

Tags: nameserver, plesk

My domain name and dedicated hosting are with different providers. I wanted to create a own nameserver for my domain name. I created 2 host object from domain registrar control panel.

1. ns.mydomain.com (IP of dedicated server)

2. ns2.mydomain.com (IP of dedicated server)

The same domain name in which I have created host object need to be hosted in my hosting. So I have assigned ns.mydomain.com, ns2.mydomain.com for the domain mydomain.com's name servers.

I hope this is correct... If not please correct me.

Then in my dedicated server (with PLESK control panel), I have enable the DNS service and created 2 A and other entries as follow records.

```
    *.webmail.mydomain.com. CNAME   mydomain.com.
192.168.100.219 / 24    PTR mydomain.com.
ftp.mydomain.com.   CNAME   mydomain.com.
mail.mydomain.com.  A   192.168.100.219
ns.mydomain.com.    A   83.138.xxx.xxx (PUBLIC IP OF THE SERVER)
ns2.mydomain.com.   A   83.138.xxx.xxx (PUBLIC IP OF THE SERVER)
mydomain.com.           NS  mydomain.com.
mydomain.com.           A   83.138.xxx.xxx (PUBLIC IP OF THE SERVER)
mydomain.com.           MX (10) mail.mydomain.com.
mydomain.com.           TXT v=spf1 +a +mx -all
webmail.mydomain.com.   A   192.168.100.219
www.mydomain.com.   NS  ns.mydomain.com.
www.mydomain.com.   NS  ns2.mydomain.com.
```

I followed these guide : http://help.godaddy.com/article/198

Is the above setting correct? Would I be able to use these name servers?

Answer (score 1):

Almost perfect !

But you should have this:

```
mydomain.com.       NS  ns.mydomain.com.
mydomain.com.       NS  ns2.mydomain.com.
```

The rest is OK (Be sure that the SOA line exist on the configuration files)

```
 #OnLinuxMachine> dig soa mydomain.com
```

If you need www.mydomain.com to work, you should add this

```
www.mydomain.com.   A   83.138.xxx.xxx (PUBLIC IP OF THE SERVER)
```

**Also, if you don't need to manage the subdomain www.mydomain.com**:

- To have MX records for it like emailaddress@www.domain.com
- To have hosts like hostabc.www.mydomain.com

You can remove theses:

```
www.mydomain.com.   NS  ns.mydomain.com.
www.mydomain.com.   NS  ns2.mydomain.com.
```

Comment: My domain are registered in irrp.net . I registrerd 2 host object ns.mydomain.com and ns2.mydomain.com for my server's public IPs. I can not see they are propogated still. What tools I can use to check them?

Comment: As @Lazy-Badger said below, use dig with your nameserver to know if they are correctly set and also, to know their TTL and with the SOA the expiration in seconds. You will then know when it will work with other Name Servers. eg.: dig @REPLACE_WITH_ns.mydomain.com_PUBLICIP) ns.mydomain.com

Comment: Also I have opened the port for DNS Query in my firewall. Still I can not see the name server is resolving to the IP I have given. Btw, I do not understand this SOA things, Is it must to do?

Comment: I think the control panel you are using is taking care of SOA for you, but you can verify with the dig command : dig @REPLACE_WITH_ns.mydomain.com_PUBLICIP soa mydomain.com

Comment: Ok Done,It is working now fine.

Answer (score 0):

Non-routable IP for mail.*  and webmail.* seems as mistake

1. Can you see zone content from ns?
2. Primary and secondary zones for the **same domain on one daemon**
   (BIND?) may be big headache, AFAIK
3. dig is your best friend on debug. Common form of it's call is

   dig @server name type

where

- @server is IP of your ns.mydomain.com.
- name is mydomain.com.
- type is AXFR|SOA etc

Better (fast) answer I can give you only with small piece of real data: IP of primary NS and domain-name, otherwise we'll continue "remote administration"

PS - I know nothing about plesk, but both PTR and A in *one zone* for me (as for hostmaster) is big bug